# Learning the Rach 3 coming from Rach 2

Tags: piano

I performed the first movement of the Rachmaninoff Concerto #2 when I was younger (no orchestra, orchestra arrangement played by a second piano).

For someone who has played the 1st movement of the Rach #3, how much more difficult is it than the 1st movement of the second concerto? For something like the [cadenza of the first movement](https://youtu.be/Jgibfppgb6A?t=650), how difficult is that to play relative to 1st concerto? Are there any 'similar parts' in difficulty from the 2nd, or is this basically a beast of its own? By the way, I'm referring more to the technical components of it, and not so much the musicality or interpretation of it.

Comment: It has been called the most technically demanding piano concerto in the standard repertoire. I think that the correct answer to "How hard is it?" is "Yes."

Comment: @KeizerHarm yes i'm aware. Have you performed either? I'm look for someone who has played both or either to comment on the difficulty **relative to the second**, which is not a cake walk either.